# Javascript bookmark add something after the uri

Tags: javascript, uri

does someone know how to create a javascript in a bookmark?

What I want is this:

A bookmark on my bookmark toolbar in chrome, that adds

> /?flush=all

so if I am on www.stackoverflow.com/questions
and I click my bookmark, then it changes to:

www.stachoverflow.com/?flush=all

is that a simple script?

Ralph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.location.href = window.location.href + '/?flush=all'
```

Comment: Hmm it doesn't work, I put this in my adress field:

javascript:(function(){http://window.location.href%20%3D%20window.location.href%20+%20%27/?flush=all%27)}();

Do you know what's wrong with this?

Comment: Nevermind this one works now:
javascript:(function()%7Bwindow.location.href %3D window.location.href %2B '%2F%3Fflush%3Dall'%7D)()